# Explain this java code please?

Tags: java

I have just copied the parts of the program that i dont fully understand, if you could explain it to me.
Thanks

// I know the first line creates a new object of the scanner class called sc
// The second line asks for input
//What does the third line do?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Initial Price");
price = sc.nextDouble();
```

Comment: You should read some introductory articles on Java first.

Comment: Scans the next token of the input as a double

Comment: and . . assigns the value to `price`

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation of `Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29):

> Scans the next token of the input as a `double`.

It basically reads from `System.in` and tries to interpret the input as a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The third line reads a double value from the scanner, which in this case means a double value from the standard input (System.in).

Answer (score 0):

The third line saves the input from the user into a variable called `price` which is of type `double` (I assume primitive type, rather than the `Double` wrapper class). Note that you'll get an exception if the user enters something that can't be converted to a double.

Answer (score 0):

Scans the next token of the input as a double.
read java doc for details

[nextDouble](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29)